# YML content not displaying in Jekyll collections

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, liquid

I am trying to display items from a collection called fiction. Nothing other than the url is displaying on the website.

[image: Screenshot of the website]

The for loop for collection is here

```
{% for fiction_item in site.fiction %}
    <ul class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
        <li class="bg-white"><img class="img-fluid card-img-top" src="{{ fiction_item.image_url }}" alt="{{ fiction_item.title }}">
            <div class="p-4 art-content">
                <h5>{{ fiction_item.title }}</h5>
                <h6>by {{ fiction_item.writer }}</h6>
                <p class="small text mb-0">{{ fiction_item.caption }}</p><a class="btn border-pretty" href="{{ site.url }}{{ fiction_item.url }}">More</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

My _config.yml is written like this

```yaml
name: The Book Project

url: '/experiment/'
baseurl: '/experiment/'

collections:
  nonfiction:
    output: true
  fiction:
    output: true
  art:
    output: true
  poetry:
    output: true

defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: "nonfiction"
    values:
      layout: "blog"
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: "fiction"
    values:
      layout: "blog"
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: "art"
    values:
      layout: "blog"
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: "poetry"
    values:
      layout: "blog"
```

The markdown content is like this:

```yaml
---
layout: blog
title: History of India
image_url: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a4/Cave_26%2C_Ajanta.jpg/348px-Cave_26%2C_Ajanta.jpg
writer: Adnan Abbasi
caption: Whendefining a collection as a sequence, its pages will not be rendered by default. To enable this, output: true must be specified on the collection, which requires defining the collection as a mapping. For more information, see the section Output. Gather your collections 3.7.0. You can optionally specify a directory to store all your collections in the same place with collections_dir: my_collections. Then Jekyll will look in my_collections/_books for the books collection, and in my ...
---

When defining a collection as a sequence, its pages will not be rendered by default. To enable this, output: true must be specified on the collection, which requires defining the collection as a mapping. For more information, see the section Output. Gather your collections 3.7.0. You When defining a collection as a sequence, its pages will not be rendered by default. To enable this, output: true must be specified on the collection, which requires defining the collection as a mapping. For more information, see the section Output. Gather your collections 3.7.0. YouWhendefining a collection as a sequence, its pages will not be rendered by default. To enable this, output: true must be specified on the collection, which requires defining the collection as a mapping. For more information, see the section Output. Gather your collections 3.7.0. You

When defining a collection as a sequence, its pages will not be rendered by default. To enable this, output: true must be specified on the collection, which requires defining the collection as a mapping. For more information, see the section Output. Gather your collections 3.7.0. You When defining a collection as a sequence, its pages will not be rendered by default. To enable this, output: true must be specified on the collection, which requires defining the collection as a mapping. For more information, see the section Output. Gather your collections 3.7.0. YouWhendefining a collection as a sequence, its pages will not be rendered by default. To enable this, output: true must be specified on the collection, which requires defining the collection as a mapping. For more information, see the section Output. Gather your collections 3.7.0. You
```

The same problem happens on individual collection page:
[image]
The link to the project is here: http://thebookproject.team/experiment/fiction.html

The link to its github is here: https://github.com/thebookproject/experiment

Where exactly am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies within the front matter of the markdown files.

When I tried building the site locally, I got an error saying that front matter parsing failed:

```
caption: blah blah collections_dir: my_collections.
```

In this line, there are multiple variable declarations, `caption:` and `collections_dir:`. To fix this, try enclosing your caption in quotes, like this:

```
caption: "blah blah collections_dir: my_collections."
```

This fixed the build error for me.